Time series modeling tips
I'm currently building a pricing time series model for a category in produce and I have some questions. This is my first time building a forecasting model at my job and I've hit a few road bumps.
The last few years have had a lot of randomness because of different factors including supply shortages and increasing input costs. Because I've been trying to use some linear models including Arima and Exponential smoothing, the randomness has caused the predictions to be all over the place.
I'm trying to predict monthly prices for this category but I've been only able to find yearly totals to use has features in the model. The yearly features seem to not make the predictions any more accurate.
I guess my question is what advice does anyone have? Should I still show my predictions and explain that the random variation will continue to throw off forecasts until we get better features or are there other techniques I could try to get better forecasts?

as a question, sir you only want to use traditional machine learning ? and how much data do you have ?
